# MojoFailureException when creating a Vaadin Maven project in Intellij

Tags: maven, windows-8.1, vaadin, java-8, intellij-13

**UPDATE:
the problem went away when I uninstalled IntelliJ from "Program Files (x86)" and installed it in "Program Files" instead**

I'm trying to start using maven/intellij to develop my vaadin applications, but when I add the archetype and click Finish it throws the following error in the console

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -Dmaven.home=C:\dev\apache-maven-3.2.3 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\dev\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin\m2.conf -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\dev\apache-maven-3.2.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=13.1.5 -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=Demooo -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application "-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST " org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:RELEASE:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom     >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] Archetype repository missing. Using the one from [com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:7.3.3] found in catalog remote
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application/LATEST /vaadin-archetype-application-LATEST .jar
[WARNING] Failed to write tracking file C:\Users\Reda\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-archetype-application\LATEST \vaadin-archetype-application-LATEST .jar.lastUpdated
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Reda\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-archetype-application\LATEST \vaadin-archetype-application-LATEST .jar.lastUpdated (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
...
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.264 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-26T11:11:21-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:LATEST ) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

I installed everything from scratch (Java SE 8, Mave 3.2.3, Intellij 13.1) and setup the enviroment variables as follows

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
M2_HOME: C:\dev\apache-maven-3.2.3
Path: ​%JAVA_HOME%\bin; %M2_HOME%\bin
```

I'm running on Windows 8.1 machine

Is there anything I'm missing or I need to configure in Intellij? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You are defining the following command line argument: `"-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST "`. Why have you added a space at the end of it? What happends if you remove the space? i.e. `"-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST"`

Comment: I haven't defined that manually. I selected the vaadin-archetype-application and it defined everything